# python、openpyxl利用して複合グラフを作成したい

Tags: python, python3, openpyxl

python、openpyxlを利用して、積上げ棒・折れ線グラフを一つのグラフエリアに表示する「複合グラフ」を作成したいです。対応方法について、ご教授願います。
また、そもそもopenpyxlを使用した場合は複合グラフの作成はサポートされていないのでしょうか？

#### Python（3.8.2）コード

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, LineChart, Reference
from openpyxl.chart.plotarea import DataTable

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("./sample.xlsx")
sh = wb['list']

labels = Reference(sh, min_col=1, max_col=1, min_row=3, max_row=sh.max_row)
data1 = Reference(sh, min_col=2, max_col=6, min_row=2, max_row=sh.max_row)
data2 = Reference(sh, min_col=5, max_col=6, min_row=2, max_row=sh.max_row)
chart = BarChart()
chart.type = "col"
chart.grouping = "stacked"

chart.overlap = 100
chart.title = "メインタイトル"
chart.y_axis.title = "数量"
chart.legend.position = 'b'
chart.add_data(data1, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(labels)

chart2 = LineChart()
chart2.add_data(data2, titles_from_data=True)

chart.height = 10
chart.width = 15

# datatable
chart.plot_area.dTable = DataTable()
chart.plot_area.dTable.showHorzBorder = True
chart.plot_area.dTable.showVertBorder = True
chart.plot_area.dTable.showOutline = True
chart.plot_area.dTable.showKeys = True

sh.add_chart(chart, "I2")
sh.add_chart(chart2, "I20")

wb.save("./sample.xlsx")
```

#### グラフ作成時の入力データ

```
    title               
date    100-10  200-10  300-10  gokei   base
9/16    15  48  41  104 50
9/17    15  48  46  109 50
9/18    15  50  50  115 50
9/19    15  50  49  114 50
9/20    15  49  49  113 50
```

※"100-10","200-10","300-10"を積上げ棒グラフ
※"gokei","base"を折れ線グラフ
※最終的には"gokei"の折れ線グラフを非表示にし、データラベルの設定を実施したい

#### 確認したこと

- グラフ単体で作成できることを確認
- グラフが複数作成できることを確認

Comment: 表示内容の調整はさておき、グラフを重ね合わせるだけならこちらのページ [Adding a second axis](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/secondary.html) の`c1 += c2`にあるように`chart += chart2`で出来るのでは？

Answer (score 0):

グラフを重ね合わせるならこちらのページ [Adding a second axis](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/secondary.html) の`c1 += c2`にあるように、質問のソースでは`chart += chart2`で出来るでしょう。

その上で以下2点は表示するデータの列を調節することで出来るでしょう。

> ※"100-10","200-10","300-10"を積上げ棒グラフ
> ※"gokei","base"を折れ線グラフ

以下のように出来ると思われます。`####`を付けたところが変更点

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, LineChart, Reference
from openpyxl.chart.plotarea import DataTable

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("./sample.xlsx")
sh = wb['list']

labels = Reference(sh, min_col=1, max_col=1, min_row=3, max_row=sh.max_row)
#### data1 = Reference(sh, min_col=2, max_col=6, min_row=2, max_row=sh.max_row)
#### data2 = Reference(sh, min_col=5, max_col=6, min_row=2, max_row=sh.max_row)
data1 = Reference(sh, min_col=2, max_col=4, min_row=2, max_row=sh.max_row) #### ※"100-10","200-10","300-10"を積上げ棒グラフ
data2 = Reference(sh, min_col=5, max_col=6, min_row=2, max_row=sh.max_row) #### ※"gokei","base"を折れ線グラフ
chart = BarChart()
chart.type = "col"
chart.grouping = "stacked"

chart.overlap = 100
chart.title = "メインタイトル"
chart.y_axis.title = "数量"
chart.legend.position = 'b'
chart.add_data(data1, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(labels)

chart2 = LineChart()
chart2.add_data(data2, titles_from_data=True)

chart.height = 10
chart.width = 15

# datatable
chart.plot_area.dTable = DataTable()
chart.plot_area.dTable.showHorzBorder = True
chart.plot_area.dTable.showVertBorder = True
chart.plot_area.dTable.showOutline = True
chart.plot_area.dTable.showKeys = True

chart += chart2 #### 複合グラフ

sh.add_chart(chart, "I2")
#### sh.add_chart(chart2, "I20") #### 2つ目の単独は表示しない

wb.save("./sample.xlsx")
```

---

その上で、以下については`DataLabelList`というものを使えば出来ると思われます。
グラフの非表示は出来るのかもしれませんが、直ぐには見当たらなかったので、最小サイズの点だけ表示して、連結の線が無いようにしてみました。

> ※最終的には"gokei"の折れ線グラフを非表示にし、データラベルの設定を実施したい

この質問で直接参考になるかは疑問ですが、良い資料にはなるでしょう。
[Pythonライブラリ(openpyxl)でExcelのグラフを作成する方法【徹底解説】](https://www.shibutan-bloomers.com/python_libraly_openpyxl-8/2947/)
[Pythonライブラリ(openpyxl)によるExcel「棒(縦棒・横棒)グラフ」の作り方とデザインレシピ【徹底解説】](https://www.shibutan-bloomers.com/python_libraly_openpyxl-10/3260/)

こちらはOpenPyXlではなくExcelだけでやる場合の記事でしょう。
[Add Total Values for Stacked Column and Stacked Bar Charts in Excel](https://anthonysmoak.com/2020/12/29/add-total-values-for-stacked-column-and-stacked-bar-charts-in-excel/)

OpenPyXlではこの辺が参考になるでしょう。
[Line Charts](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/line.html)
[class openpyxl.chart.marker.Marker](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.chart.marker.html#openpyxl.chart.marker.Marker)
[class openpyxl.chart.label.DataLabelList](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.chart.label.html?highlight=datalabellist#openpyxl.chart.label.DataLabelList)

最初のものに追加/変更して以下のようにしてみました。

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, LineChart, Reference
from openpyxl.chart.label import DataLabel, DataLabelList
from openpyxl.chart.plotarea import DataTable

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("./sample.xlsx")
sh = wb['list']

labels = Reference(sh, min_col=1, max_col=1, min_row=3, max_row=sh.max_row)
#### data1 = Reference(sh, min_col=2, max_col=6, min_row=2, max_row=sh.max_row)
#### data2 = Reference(sh, min_col=5, max_col=6, min_row=2, max_row=sh.max_row)
data1 = Reference(sh, min_col=2, max_col=4, min_row=2, max_row=sh.max_row) #### ※"100-10","200-10","300-10"を積上げ棒グラフ
#### "gokei"と"base"の表示形式を分けるために分割 ####
data2 = Reference(sh, min_col=5, max_col=5, min_row=2, max_row=sh.max_row) #### ※"gokei"を折れ線グラフ
data3 = Reference(sh, min_col=6, max_col=6, min_row=2, max_row=sh.max_row) #### ※"base"を折れ線グラフ
chart = BarChart()
chart.type = "col"
chart.grouping = "stacked"

chart.overlap = 100
chart.title = "メインタイトル"
chart.y_axis.title = "数量"
chart.legend.position = 'b'
chart.add_data(data1, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(labels)

chart2 = LineChart() #### "gokei"
chart2.add_data(data2, titles_from_data=True)

chart3 = LineChart() #### "base"
chart3.add_data(data3, titles_from_data=True) ####

chart.height = 10
chart.width = 15

# datatable
chart.plot_area.dTable = DataTable()
chart.plot_area.dTable.showHorzBorder = True
chart.plot_area.dTable.showVertBorder = True
chart.plot_area.dTable.showOutline = True
chart.plot_area.dTable.showKeys = True

#### "gokei" を最小サイズの点で表示し、連結の線を表示せず、数値をラベル表示する
s1 = chart2.series[0]
s1.marker.symbol = "dot"
s1.marker.size   = 2
s1.graphicalProperties.line.noFill = True
chart2.dataLabels = DataLabelList(dLblPos='t')
chart2.dataLabels.showVal = True
#### ここまで

chart += chart2 #### "gokei"を合成
chart += chart3 #### "base"を合成

sh.add_chart(chart, "I2")
#### sh.add_chart(chart2, "I20") #### 2つ目の単独は表示しない

wb.save("./sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: 早々のご回答ありがとうございます。
ご提示いただきました内容を確認させていただきました。
実現できました。
また、本題プラスアルファで回答いただいたことを感謝します。 取り急ぎお礼まで。